# Tomcat 7.0.52 APR 1.1.29 native TLS Protocol Session Renegotiation Security Vulnerability TLS SSL Man In The Middle CVE-2009-3555

Tags: security, ssl, tomcat7, apr

I am failing a server security scan on Windows 2008 R2, with

TLS Protocol Session Renegotiation Security Vulnerability TLS SSL Man In The Middle CVE-2009-3555

The scan results recommend an upgrade to openssl 0.9.8l or higher.

I am using the latest version of tcnative-1.dll (1.1.29 13/02/14) which, as I understand it is built using the native libraries and openssl libraries.

Is the only way I can resolve this is to build tcnative myself with the latest version of openssl?

Looking at the http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/ build section I need MS Visual Studio (which I don't have and have never used).

Has anybody else build it?  If so I cannot find it.

Comment: The 1.1.29 binary provided by the Apache Software Foundation was built with OpenSSL 1.0.1e (you should see a log message to that effect when Tomcat starts) so the OpenSSL version is not the problem. I need to do some testing to see what is going on here.

Comment: Thanks Mark, yes just noticed that.  I really have no idea what I should do then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This result is a false positive. I've performed various tests with various versions of Tomcat using the 1.1.29 APR/native connector and in none of those test did insecure renegotiation occur.

Note that Tomcat - depending on version, connector and configuration may support secure renegotiation.

The most definitive test was with OpenSSL 0.9.8.k (i.e. a version of OpenSSL that is vulnerable to CVE2009-3555 and will attempt an insecure renegotiation). When I try this, the connection blocks and eventually times out.

You need to find a better security scanner.

For completeness, the output of the test was:

```
$ ./openssl s_client -connect 192.168.23.9:8443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=US/CN=ca-test.tomcat.apache.org
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/CN=localhost
   i:/C=US/CN=ca-test.tomcat.apache.org
 1 s:/C=US/CN=ca-test.tomcat.apache.org
       i:/C=US/CN=ca-test.tomcat.apache.org
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/CN=localhost
issuer=/C=US/CN=ca-test.tomcat.apache.org
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2433 bytes and written 322 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: E98ED9D885D761C7B23AF93DC15C53D0680AF2D8345A37699549E48C9D4E18AE
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: FA2C87FB24C68186D1CC63FEEF459B7DE4BA0F304D60F2293AB3C1C23DF03566F51DDB61A9576A1FE9C021CB3438B4C7
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1395309769
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
---
GET / HTTP/1.0
R
RENEGOTIATING
7087:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:530:
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I have contacted the scanner company.